# Конвертация одномерного массива в ступенчатый массив

Tags: c#, массивы, visual-studio-2010

Есть одномерный массив и есть ступенчатый, например есть строка

```
int[] a = new int[12] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

Нужно получить двумерный массив такого вида

```
int[][] b = new int [n][]; // К примеру n = 3
b[0] = new int [m] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };// А m = 4
b[1] = new int [m] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
b[2] = new int [m] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

То есть одномерный массив разбить на n строк по m символов.

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали, и что не получается?

Comment: Не знаю как реализовать эту функцию.

Comment: так что вы пробовали? Вообще ничего?

Comment: Не получается преобразовать, пытался сделать циклы для преобразования, но не смог.

Comment: Черновик -- в студию!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не забываем подключить `using System.Linq;`

```
            var a = new int[12] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
            var n = 3;
            var m = 4;
            var b = new int[n][];
            var index = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < a.Length;)
            {
                b[index] = a.Skip(i).Take(m).ToArray();
                i = i + m;
                index++;
            }
```

Обязательное условие, `что m*n == длине массива`, иначе обрабатываем исключения.

Comment: На тот случай, если кому-то нужна production реализация batching'a, то, на мой взгляд, стоит смотреть [в сторону `MoreLINQ.Batch(...)`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)